# Google Analytics--My second profile to an existing domain not tracking

Tags: google-analytics, profile

I created a second profile to my Analytics account to track SEO keywords.  This is a second profile for my existing working domain.  It has been 4 days and I still do not see any traffic on this secondary profile.  The profile shows a Staus of "Unknown".  But I do not see a way to validate it like you have to when you create your first profile and this should not be necessary for a profile to my existing domain.  Any ideas what I am missing?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you have 2 profiles for a single site with both tracking codes?

Comment: I have a primary profile for my website which has been working for over a year.  I went into profiles and created a new profile for an "existing" domain.  Its just second profile for the original website.  This is to create different views of data using filters.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the URL of the site? Maybe the guys here or me can see if there's anything wrong from there.

Comment: Sure, the website is www.dudeimgettingmarried.com and the current Tracking Status that shows up under each profile is "Receiving Data."

Comment: Maybe a second profile does not gather data by default, you have to enable filters first?  I assumed it would gather everything the primary does and then you filter out what you want.

Comment: I got exactly the same problem, i've set up some filters but it does not work neither

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem.  This solution worked for me.

1. Click **Edit** beside the profile that
   is giving you problems.
2. On the upper-right of the page click
   the **Check Status** link

This should jump-start Google Analytics.

Solution found at:
http://www.inficone.com/technology/a-solution-to-google-analytics-tracking-unknown-problem/151/

Answer (score 0):

Without much info, here's what I can offer:

[Why is Google Analytics not tracking some of the pages on my website?](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55615)
Or [contact Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/request.py?fhc=1).